# How to fix unique "key" prop and validateDOMNesting(...) in ReactJS with fuctional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi all I have following [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-benz-9ec13m).

Test.js component

```
    const Test = ({ infoText }) => {
      return (
        <div>
          Some Text
          {infoText && <p>{infoText}</p>}
        </div>
      );
    };

export default Test;
```

App.js component

```
    export default function App() {
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <Test
            infoText={[
              <p className="someStyles">"Looking to lease multiple devices?"</p>,
              <div className="someOtherStyles">
                 <b>Get in contact with our specialist.</b>
              </div>,
            ]}
           />
         </div>
      );
    }
```

When I am rendering my `Test` component in `App.js` file I am getting errors like

`Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.`

`Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <div> cannot appear as a descendant of <p>.`

I know that is coming from this syntax that I wrote.

```
     infoText={[
              <p className="someStyles">"Looking to lease multiple devices?"</>,
              <div className="someOtherStyles">
                 <b>Get in contact with our specialist.</b>
              </div>,
            ]}
```

I need to write in this way because  my `Test` component is reusable component and I am using it's `infoText` prop for passing various tags with specific classes.

By the way, the code works. But it's very ugly that I have so many errors in the console. Please help me fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This warning is generated because usually, when a react element is an *array*, that array is generated dynamically, and so might change. In this scenario, you absolutely need the elements in your list to have a unique key prop to avoid unexpected behaviour from React.

In this scenario, you are absolutely fine to ignore the warnings, because your array is hardcoded, and is never going to change. If you don't want to see these warnings, you could change the array to be a react [fragment](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html), like this:

```
const Test = ({ infoText }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      Some Text
      {infoText && <p>{infoText}</p>}
    </div>
  );
};

<Test
  infoText={
    <>
      <p className="someStyles">"Looking to lease multiple devices?"</p>
      <div className="someOtherStyles">
        <b>Get in contact with our specialist.</b>
      </div>
    </>
  }
/>
```

A more idiomatic way of achieving the same thing might be to have your `Test` component render its children, like this:

```
const Test = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      Some Text
      <p>{children}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

<Test>
  <p className="someStyles">"Looking to lease multiple devices?"</p>
  <div className="someOtherStyles">
    <b>Get in contact with our specialist.</b>
  </div>
</Test>
```

Comment: Thank you @Ben Wainwright , it's worked for me.